# Scrapy Wikipedia: Yield does not show all rows

Tags: scrapy

I am trying to get the GDP Estimate (Under IMF) from the following page:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_GDP_(nominal)

However, I am only getting the first row (93,863,851). Here's the Scrapy Spider code:

```py
def parse(self, response):
    title = response.xpath("(//tbody)[3]")
    for country in title:
        yield {'GDP': country.xpath(".//td[3]/text()").get()}
```

On other hand, I can use getall() method to get all the data but this brings all data points into one single cell when I export it to CSV/XLSX. So this is not a solution for me.

How can I get all the datapoints via the loop? Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your selector is not correct. You should loop through the table rows and yield the data that you need. See sample below.

```py
import scrapy


class TestSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'test'
    start_urls = ['https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_GDP_(nominal)']

    def parse(self, response):
        for row in response.xpath("//caption/parent::table/tbody/tr"):
            yield {
                "country": row.xpath("./td[1]/a/text()").get(),
                "region": row.xpath("./td[2]/a/text()").get(),
                "imf_est": row.xpath("./td[3]/text()").get(),
                "imf_est_year": row.xpath("./td[4]/text()").get(),
                "un_est": row.xpath("./td[5]/text()").get(),
                "un_est_year": row.xpath("./td[6]/text()").get(),
                "worldbank_est": row.xpath("./td[7]/text()").get(),
                "worldbank_est_year": row.xpath("./td[8]/text()").get(),
            }
```

Comment: Thank you so much! it works! :)) Do you have any suggestion on how can I improve on Xpath targeting? Although I know xpath selectors I do not have a systematic grip on this matter.

Comment: You can learn more about xpath from [here](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp)